# Does firebase nodejs sdk do disk based offline persistence?

Tags: firebase

We are implementing a firebase based nodejs application on IoT device that does not have a reliable internet connection. The device records some data and pushes it to a firebase endpoint. The device has sufficient (32 GB) memory. The device may restart multiple times in a day. And it may not get an internet for 2-3 days in a stretch.

Does the nodejs firebase sdk log operation on disk for offline persistence?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disk-based persistence is currently only supported in Firebase's Android and iOS SDKs. The NodeJS package does not support disk-based persistence.

Comment: Then what strategy do you suggest we should employ to achieve firebase goodness with disk persistence in this case?

Comment: You can either roll your own local persistence layer or wait for Firebase to implement disk based persistence for node.js. Sorry for the incredibly broad advice, but there's simply not a lot more I can offer here.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen How can I load messages from disk if there is no internet connection?